Redirect to external url & get the response back in angular
My App (http://example.com) is redirecting to external url(https://externalurl.com) for login. For redirecting to external host i am using window.location.href='https://externalurl.com' & able to redirect. Here, we are providing the credential then click on submit. This external url is handing the authentication & generating a auth code. My app has to get this auth code.
Once our app is redirecting to external app then its not waiting for response.
in login.ts
loginPage(): void {
   let result =  this.authService.login()
                .then((data: any) => {
                    console.log("data is: ",data);
                })
                .catch((err: any) => {
                  console.log("error is: ",err);
                });
  }

in authservice.ts
async login(): Promise<any> {
    console.log("called login in authservice");
    let result = await this.loginToExt();
    return result;
  }
 0
  async loginToExt(): Promise<any> {
    console.log("called authservice");
    return window.location.href='https://externalurl.com';
  }

Need some help here on how we can get the response back.

Use window.opener.postMessage - subscribe

You need to change your approach. You should not and can not wait for any response in this case. Just redirect to external website and that's all. Now coming to your question that "how to get the auth code in my angular app", the external application after successful authentication must redirect the browser to your application URL with auth code in URL, something like this:
http://example.com/home#auth_code=abcd1234 

or
http://example.com/home?auth_code=abcd1234 

in your angular component you can get these parameter via ActivatedRoute service.

Thanks for the answer. Yes we are getting the response back like: http://example.com/home?auth_code=abcd1234  will try the approach u suggested.
